# Custom WordPress Theme: Only Two Pages showing blank screen?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

My WordPress pages "Gallery" and "Events" are showing blank screen, but the other pages the older ones I created) still work

I have tried to increase the memory php.ini from 30 to 180, but that had no effect. Something is wrong with the theme code because if I install a wordpress theme i.e. twentyeleven theme, the pages show.

**php.ini.production file**

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Resource Limits ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
; http://php.net/max-execution-time
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to 0 for the CLI SAPI
max_execution_time = 180
```

I'm not sure what code is causing the error, so here is the link to the site: http://radian3.com/ and the one of the blank pages: http://radian3.com/events/

**UPDATE 1**

I am adding the page.php file that is used to display the pages:

```
<?php 
/* CONTACT PAGE */
if( is_page("102")) { ?>

    <?php get_header(); ?>

    <div class="main-content" >
        <div class="about-container">
            <div class="contact-wrapper">
                    <b class="about-title">CONTACT US</b>
                <div class="about-icon-wrapper">
                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/down-arrow.png" alt="about-icon" width="50%;">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="contact-body-wrapper">
                <div class="contact-col-1">
                    <div class="contact-headline">
                        <b id="primary-headline">CONTACT FORM</b>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="content-wrapper">

                        <?php    echo do_shortcode("[contact-form-7 id='191' title='Contact form 1']");  ?>
                    </div>

                </div>      
                <div class="contact-col-2">
                    <div class="in-touch-headline">
                        <b id="primary-headline">GET IN TOUCH</b>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="touch-content-wrapper">
                        <p>For all other enquiries  and information please contact us    </p>

                        <div class="touch-content-post">
                            <div class="contact-icon-wrap">
                                <img class="touch-img" src="img/iphone-icon.jpg">
                            </div>
                            <article class="touch-content">
                                <p>1800 243 6500</p>
                                <p>1800 555 5440</p>
                            </article>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="touch-content-wrapper">
                        <div class="touch-content-post">
                            <div class="contact-icon-wrap">
                            <img class="touch-img" src="img/msg-icon.jpg">

                            </div>
                            <article class="touch-content"> 
                                <p>info@ipesite.com</p>
                            </article>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="touch-content-wrapper">
                        <div class="touch-content-post">
                            <div class="contact-icon-wrap">
                                <img class="touch-img" src="img/location-icon.jpg">
                            </div>
                            <article class="touch-content">
                                <p>25/153 Mujanjii st,<br> Hawker ACT 2614 Australia</p>
                            </article>
                        </div>
                    </div>      
                </div>              



            </div>  

        </div> <!--  / END about-container -->

    </div><!--  /main-content -->
    <?php get_footer(); ?>

</body>
</html>

<?php 
}
?>

<!--  ABOUT PAGE -->
<?php  if(is_page('84')) { ?>

    <?php  get_header(); ?>

        <div class="about-container">
            <div class="about-image-wrapper">
                    <b class="about-title">ABOUT US</b>
                <div class="about-icon-wrapper">
                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/down-arrow.png" alt="about-icon" width="50%;">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="about-content-wrapper">
                <div class="about-content-headline">
                    <b id="primary-headline">COMPANY OVERVIEW</b>
                </div>  
                <div class="about-content-post">
                    <article>
                        <p>
    <br><b id="secondary-headline">Working on new generation investors</b><br>
    Institute of professional excellence was formed in April, 2017 with the vision of its two founder directors Shahid Al and Syed Najib ul Hasan. </p>
    <p>
        It aims to introduce new investors to Pakistani equity market by attracting them to PSX. Both the founders firmly  believe transformation of "Saving culture" to  the "equity culture" is the need of the time. Not enough work is being carried out in this regard. The institute will work towards developing a new generation investors with an aim of developing a new stream of entrepreneurs.
    </p>
    <p>
        <br><b id="secondary-headline">Partnership and joint certification initiatives</b><br>
    IPE initiatives, include partnerships (with Educational boards, universities ,other institutes, and also corporate sector) through specific courses on investment strategies, entrepreneurship and equity market.
    </p>
    <p>
        The institute is working on its  upcoming courses as joint certification programs, with an aim to develop new market professionals, investors and entrepreneurs.
    </p>
    <p>
        IPE will engage general public by conducting financial workshops, seminars, short courses and even by launching various comprehensive courses at universities which would serve  in MBA program as a major in Capital markets.
    </p>
    <p>
        <br><b id="secondary-headline">Bridging the gap between public and Capital market</b><br>
    IPE  will aggressively intensify its outreach and advertising programs directed at younger Pakistanis by  promoting financial literacy as a necessary life skill.
    </p>
    <p>
        The main motivation to setup this institute was to fill up a huge vacuum  already exist between Pakistani financial markets and the new generation.
    </p><br>
    <p>
        IPE aims to provide customised solutions for new potential investors and potential employees who are struggling  to enter Pakistani  Financial markets due to gap in their knowledge and skills, demanded in those markets.
    </p><br>
    <p>
        <br><b id="secondary-headline">Helping in Career Opportunities</b><br>
    We will not only educate and prepare our students to get advantage of financial markets as an investor or an employee (whatever way they pick and choose). But we will also extend our services to recommend successful students to employers looking for trained employees in PSX, CDC and brokerage houses. We are in contact with employers in PSX and we are in a very ideal and credible position to recommend our successful students on regular basis whenever any opportunity pops up in employment areas.<br><br>No need to mention our certification would also help our students besides direct recommendation.<br>
    </p>
    <p>
        <br><b id="secondary-headline">Corporate Projects and Services</b><br>
    Besides, our educational endeavors mentioned as above we have a bunch of prestigious senior professionals who would engage with us in different corporate projects time to time depending on their area of expertise. So we are ever ready to serve corporate sector with projects of commercial value as a consultancy.

    </p>
    <p>
        <br><b id="secondary-headline">Upcoming Events</b><br>
    We are scheduling seminars and workshops to guide how to  be successful in Pakistani equity market as an investor.
    Soon we will start updating future events for our viewers too.

    </p>
    <p>
        <br>There are few more projects in pipeline and we will update each of them in appropriate time As currently we need to comply with constraint of confidentiality issues with our clients.<br>
    </p>
    <p>
        <br>Keep visiting this site in future. We will come up with surprises for you.<br><br>Thanks<br>
    Shahid Ali and Syed Hasan
    </p>
                    </article>
                </div>

            </div>      
        </div> <!--  / END about-container -->

    <?php  get_footer(); ?>


<?php } ?>

<!--  Our Team PAGE -->
<?php  if(is_page('172')) { ?>

    <?php get_header(); ?>

        <div class="about-container">
            <div class="about-team-wrapper">
                    <b class="about-title">OUR TEAM</b>
                <div class="about-icon-wrapper">
                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/down-arrow.png" alt="about-icon" width="50%;">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="about-content-wrapper">
                <div class="about-content-headline">
<!--                    <b id="primary-headline">BOARD OF DIRECTORS</b>
 -->                </div>  
                <div class="about-content-team">

                    <div class="our-team-wrap">
                        <div class="team-image-wrap">
                            <img src="img/shahid.jpg" alt="director-name">
                            <p><b>Shahid Ali</b></p>
                        </div>
                        <article class="director-bio">
                            <p>Mr. Ali is a commerce graduate and an associate member of ICMAP since 1990. He started his carrier as banker at UBL in 1974. Before joining Pakistan Capital Market in 1991 he also worked as head of costing department in leather and textile garments industries.<br><br>

                            He had worked at top management positions at local as well as international equity broking firms those includes W. I. Carr (Far East), J. P. Morgan Chass (formerly Jardine Flemings Pakistan, Orix Investment Bank Al Hoqani Securities and Investment Corporation, Habib Metropolitan Financial Services and BIPL Securities (formerly KASB Sec. Ltd). He was CEO of last four companies mentioned as above.<br><br>

                            He is among few pioneers in 1991 who took the corporate brokerage house culture in K.S.E to next level by establishing 8 different corporate brokerage houses, most of them with foreign Joint ventures, after foreigners being allowed to enter in Pakistan equity markets.</p>
                        </article>
                    </div>
                    <div class="our-team-wrap">
                        <div class="team-image-wrap">
                            <img src="img/najib.jpg" alt="director-name">
                            <p><b>Najib Ul-Hasan</b></p>
                        </div>
                        <article class="director-bio">
                            <p>
                                He is an international business coach and qualified from University of Canberra, Australia and Australian Employment Inc. Author of dozen of e-books and 6 courses related to various business management topics. He has an extensive corporate exposure at top management level in Australia and Pakistan. His passion is Forex and stock trading, coaching, and consultancy, all with great success throughout.<br><br>

                            Also done 6 professional courses from I.CM.A. In his earlier times, he became a double graduate from University of Karachi in Commerce and Arts faculty. <br><br>

                            Australia (2001-2016)
                            Director in Tall Trees Motel, Project Director in Aus Pak Soft Solutions pty Ltd, Senior Manager Operations in Cybos pty Ltd
                            In his last 5 years in Australia he started working as business coach, consultant and mentor for entrepreneurs for both online and offline business models, in Australia and worldwide and was successful in his coaching venture.<br><br>
                            Pakistan (1987- 2000)
                            Head of Settlements in ING Barings, Deputy Manager in ISL, Production director in Jawad Garments, Financial controller in Pakistan Wire Industries, Cost Accountant in B.P Food Industries.<br><br>
                            He had a unique experience of  setting up ING Barings entire systems and training stock office staff from scratch and running the stock office operations successfully. Also he contributed  in the event of its winding up. He had similar experience in ISL (a JV with Smith New Court, Hongkong that was a subsidiary of Merrill Lynch) for starting the stock office operations from scratch and running that successfully. 
                            </p>
                        </article>
                    </div>                  
                </div>

            </div>      
        </div> <!--  / END about-container -->

        <?php get_footer() ?>

        <?php  } ?>


        <!--  Our Members Data PAGE -->
<?php  if(is_page('176')) { ?>

    <?php get_header(); ?>

        <div class="about-container">
            <div class="about-members-wrapper">
                    <b class="about-title">MEMBERS DATA BANK</b>
                <div class="about-icon-wrapper">
                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/down-arrow.png" alt="about-icon" width="50%;">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="about-content-wrapper">
                <div class="about-content-headline">
                    <b id="primary-headline">OUR GRADUATES</b>
                </div>  
                <div class="about-content-post">
                    <article>
                        <p>
                        <br><b id="secondary-headline">Institute of professional excellence</b><br>
                        In compliance to our own mission we encourage our successful students to submit their resume to us. As we help our members (successful students) to find great employment or project opportunities in the open market. We are in contact with employers and corporate world and we want our members to get best value from this.</p><br><br>
                        <p>Good luck.</p>



                    </article>
                </div>

            </div>      
            <div class="about-content-wrapper">
                <div class="about-content-headline">
                    <b id="primary-headline">ALREADY GRADUATED?</b>
                </div>  
                <div class="about-content-post">
                    <article id="content-margin-left">
                        <br>
                        <p>Have you already graduated? Contact us to join our Alumni group for any opportunities.</p>
                        <br><br><br>

                        <p><b id="secondary-headline">Contact:</b></p><br>
                        <p>Mr Shahid Ali                        0333 2238 461</p><br>
                        <p>Mr Syed Najib ul Hasan               0335 2522 775</p>


                    </article>
                </div>

            </div>              
        </div> <!--  / END about-container -->





    <?php get_footer(); ?>

<?php   } ?>


        <!--  Our Mission PAGE -->
<?php  if(is_page('174')) { ?>

    <?php get_header(); ?>

        <div class="about-container">
            <div class="about-mission-image-wrapper">
                    <b class="about-title">OUR MISSION</b>
                <div class="about-icon-wrapper">
                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/down-arrow.png" alt="about-icon" width="50%;">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="about-content-wrapper">
                <div class="about-content-headline">
                    <b id="primary-headline">MISSION STATEMENT</b>
                </div>  
                <div class="about-content-post">
                    <article>
                        <p>
    <br><b id="secondary-headline">Institute of professional excellence</b><br><br><i><blockquote>
    "Institute of professional excellence being a partner in nation building acknowledges its noble duty towards the society to educate new stream of investors and professionals in the capital market" </blockquote><br></i> </p>

    <p>
        <br><b id="secondary-headline">Our Mission</b><br>
    To take a leadership role in providing  value to business world and education sector by creating a new generation of investors and professionals in capital market.
    </p>

    <p>
        <br><b id="secondary-headline">Our Vision</b><br>
        1.  To serve our community and society by adding value in our courses with research, and innovative work that adheres to a blend of industry based competency with academic content.
    </p>
    <p><br>
        2. To follow our set  "Standards of financial literacy" in all our courses to ensure quality and a structured approach.
    </p><br>

    <p>
        <b id="secondary-headline">Business model</b><br>
We create value with high quality courses much needed in the capital market at different levels. We  offer our training and courses in partnership with corporate sectors, universities and other institutes who are seeking to increase employability skills in their students together with academic value.
    </p>
    <p>
        <br><b id="secondary-headline">Our Strategy</b><br>
To provide competency based training for professionals, investors and entrepreneurs by means of publicly accessible credentialing programs for establishing industry specific excellence.

    </p>
    <p><br>
    To work with corporate sector as a partner or consultant in projects with commercial value related to capital market.   To build up community and deliver to all members the value that would provide them an edge to to excel with confidence in capital market.
    </p>
    <p>
        <br><b id="secondary-headline">Our Core Values</b><br>
To provide quality and value for money with highest professional integrity and confidentiality to all clients, students and related entities.
    </p>

                    </article>
                </div>

            </div>      
        </div> <!--  / END about-container -->


    <?php  get_footer(); ?>

    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: A blank screen really just means "something went wrong", so its difficult to know whats causing it. However because its only on 2 pages for you and they work in the default theme, then its most likely a PHP error in the template used on those pages - probably a syntax error, or maybe they use `<?` or `<?=` instead of `<?php`. Take a look at the templates and start there!

Comment: @FluffyKitten thanks for your comment. So I've added the page.php file to the Question,  maybe I am doing something wrong on this page with regards to php code structure? Not sure, although I have checked for <?php ?> syntax - nothing there i believe

Comment: Very first thing, `<?php 
/* CONTACT PAGE */
if( is_page("102")) { ?>`, this condition itself is static. Prevent this types of coding. What if you delete that contact page and have to create new one. Will you again open up your php file and edit the ID ? Stop passing ID, slug in condition. This is not the dynamic way. Very simple way to follow, you can create page templates and then proceed. This is not the good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are only displaying content for 5 pages!

Your page.php only outputs content for these pages:

```
/* CONTACT PAGE */
if( is_page("102")) { ?>
    [...]
<!--  ABOUT PAGE -->
<?php  if(is_page('84')) { ?>
    [...]    
<!--  Our Team PAGE -->
<?php  if(is_page('172')) { ?>
    [...]    
<!--  Our Members Data PAGE -->
<?php  if(is_page('176')) { ?>
    [...]    
<!--  Our Mission PAGE -->
<?php  if(is_page('174')) { ?>
    [...]
```

For every other page, you aren't outputting anything so you're getting a blank screen.

My big concern is why are you displaying the content in this way?

Firstly, the content itself should be coming from the content editor in the WP pages. 
I understand if you're recreating a site from an existing HTML one, this might just be your first step. But by putting your content into WP instead of hard-coding it, you will find that in most cases you can reuse the same template for every page.

More importantly, don't throw everything into page.php - you currently have your entire site content in it! if each page needs a different structure (or if you really need to hard-code your content into each page), you should be creating individual templates.

It looks like you're brand new to WP, so I suggest you do some tutorials about creating a theme and developing for WP, because when you're not doing it the right way you're just going to run into more & more problems :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I realised the issue. Perhaps i need to go back to lynda.com tutorial for wordpress with underscores. Btw is this approach sound moving forward: on the page.php I should have a  basic template that can be used for every page and if I need more customised design on a particular page create a template layout, right?

Comment: @Shaz Yes, a basic page.php template and customised templates are the way to go - that's exactly what WP is set up for! Look up WP hierarchies and templates to see how it works. There are lots of tutorials out there. Learning by video isn't the best way - its easier to use one that you can go through at your own pace step by step, and try the examples along the way. [WP's Theme Development page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) is always a good place to start! As this answer found the problem, you can accept it to mark your question as resolved (and we both get some rep :) !)

Comment: @Shaz Here's the [WP Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) - it's a invaluable reference to have for custom template files. And a tutorial I found handy (though I'm not sure how up-to-date it is now) [WordPress Theme Tutorial](https://themeshaper.com/2012/10/22/the-themeshaper-wordpress-theme-tutorial-2nd-edition/), and a short tutorial for starting a theme from an existing site: [How To Create Your Own Custom WordPress Theme](https://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-your-own-custom-wordpress-theme). But there are loads more if you Google!

Comment: Okay one more question: If I create a basic page.php template where I simply include get_header() and get_footer() functions, am I still able to add content through the wordpress create page editor or no?

Comment: Or since it is a template i cannot add content through a wordpress editor? Thanks for the resources!

Comment: @Shaz A template just creates the structure for you to include the content from the WP editor, although you can hardcode content too. You use WP's functions to get the content. The best thing to do is use an existing theme such as twentyseventeen as a reference - make a copy of page.php from it as your starting point (you can delete the code including comments if you aren't using them). But go through the tutorials, they explain it better & in more detail. You might need to do a few different ones to get the hang of everything but it will be worth it... and easier to maintain!

Comment: thanks for your response, will def. implement on it!

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that you have just one "index" page in the `/events/` folder. When I go to `/events/index.html`, a working page appears, but `/events/index.php` returns a blank page. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Its very unlikely that's the problem - apart from the fact that you can have 2 index files in a folder (the server will have a setting to determine which is the default),  If that was the problem, the WP default theme wouldn't work either.